# Outputstreams weird behaviour with big data

Tags: java, output

I am using Java and trying to save a lot of double values into a file like this:

```
DataOutputStream DO = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(theFileName)));
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectives; i++) {
    for (int a = 0; a < numberOfActions; a++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < numberOfStates; s++) {
            DO.writeDouble( valueFunction.get(i)[a][s] );
        }
    }                
}
DO.close();
```

I have noticed one weird behaviour. If the size of the data is less then 100Mb then everything is OK. But if the size of the data is bigger than 100Mb then java just starts writing to the file from the beginning.

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: I strongly suspect there's something wrong with your diagnostics (or your data) rather than with Java. DataOutputStream and FileOutputStream are easily capable of handling hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: I agree with Skeet, maybe you are executing this code twice and overwriting the file